# Which stat does Eldritch Blast use when grabbing it from the Spell Sniper feat?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

Eldritch Blast is a Warlock cantrip, and Warlocks use their Charisma for their spells, even when you multiclass.
If I have Gale the Wizard (whose spellcasting stat is Intelligence) learn the Spell Sniper feat at level 4, which gives me a cantrip, and I choose Eldritch Blast even though I have no levels in Warlock, **will Eldritch Blast use Gale's Intelligence, or his Charisma?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one instance where Baldur's Gate 3 differs from 5th edition.

The short answer is: the attribute used is whatever it says the attribute is when you're picking it.

[image]
[image]

For Gale, as a Wizard, this means **INT**. For any spellcasting class, it seems to use whatever your primary class' spellcasting ability is. (**WIS** for Clerics / Druids / Rangers, **CHA** for Bards / Warlocks / Paladins)

For anyone without spellcasting, it seems to use **INT**.

Comment: What does primary class mean? The one chose at character creation, or the one you have the most levels in?

Comment: @CodesInChaos First one, I *think*. Like how my Rogue/Ranger Astarion still has a tab that says "Rogue" despite having more Ranger levels.

Comment: @RavenDreamer afaik, the game will use the last class you multiclassed to.

Also spell casting modifier for non casters is INT for Rogue/Fighter and weirdly enough, CHA for Barb.